# Как узнать, что пользователь вошел в систему Windows?

Tags: windows, c, c++

Как узнать, что пользователь вошел в систему (Windows 2000 и более новые)?

Необходимо в Win-сервисе узнать, что пользователь интерактивно вошел в систему. Получить некоторое уведомление или еще что то.
Какие есть способы узнать это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Варианты.

1. Для Windows 2000, XP, 2003 - создать пакет уведомления [Winlogon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380545(v=VS.85).aspx).
2. Для Windows Vista, 7 - подписаться на службу системных сообщений [SENSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185680(v=VS.85).aspx).

Еще API для удаленного рабочего стола содержит уведомление [`WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828(v=vs.85).aspx).
И возможно, что WMI класс [Win32_LogonSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394189(v=vs.85).aspx) может содержать нужные события.

Comment: Спасибо, помогла подписка на сообщения Sense. Причем работает во всех ссистемах, а не только в Vista & Seven.

Answer (score -1):

Есть скрипты которые выполняются при входе в систему - смотреть в локальной политике безопасности.

Comment: Ну и что, что они есть? Ваш ответ не ясен.

Comment: Ну так это способ сказать вашей программе что пользователь вошел в систему) А вот уже как это должно взаимодействовать с вашей программой - это вам придумывать. Хотите - можете файл оставлять в какой нибудь папке.

Comment: Запуск файла, скрипта... при входе в систему не вариант, поскольку нужен момент входа, а не окончание инициализации рабочего стола. К тому же не надежно, поскольку пользователь может удалить этот файл, скрипт... и он не запуститься.

Comment: Есть ветка Run в реестре и еще много всяких мест, откуда можно запустить скрипт.

Comment: Уважаемый gecube, могу я узнать причину минуса?

Comment: Да как всегда. Вспомните наш спор про 'перегрузку switch'. Скрипты - дело хорошее, но к теме вопроса имеют отношение малое. Во-первых, скрипты могут не исполниться. Или, например, они будут исполняться все время при любом типе входа в систему. Во-вторых, их наличие не дает ответа на вопрос 'как из службы получить уведомление'. IAZ, кстати, тоже правильные моменты поднял.
Ответ пользователя userx, в противовес, кратко и по существу. PS: специально валить Вас везде цели у меня нет и не будет. Но этот ответ не нравится.

Comment: Был конкретный вопрос:"Как узнать, что пользователь вошел в систему (Windows 2000 и более новые)?". Я на него ответил и не понимаю чем этот ответ вам не нравится. Скрипты могут не исполнятся как и ваш сервис может не работать, не запускаться и т.д. ваш компьютер может не включатся и что дальше? Все может почему то не срабатывать, я не вижу связи с вопросом этого факта.